# PDO Query : Count related and repeated values then inner join

Tags: php, sql

I work with PHP and PDO.
So I have 2 tables like,

Table 1

```
| id | name | age |
| 1  | John |  25 |
| 2  | Tom  |  32 |
| 3  | James|  45 |
```

Table 2

```
| id |  Comment  | Link |
| 1  | some text |  3   |
| 2  | some text |  3   |
| 3  | some text |  1   |
```

So, Link column numbers represent id's in table1. For example Link = 3s in table 2 represent James in table 1. I need a query which brings all table1's data and also a number of repeated value for related Link column which comes from table2.

For example, the query should give me (let's choose James),

```
| id | name  | age | Value |
| 3  | James | 45  |   2   |
```

value=2, because there are two 3s in link column which related to James

I tried somethings but got lots of errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.age,
       count(*) as value
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.link
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.age
```

If you really want just one row then add `WHERE`

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.age,
       count(*) as value
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.link
WHERE a.name = 'James'
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.age
```

or use subquery

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.age,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 b WHERE a.id = b.link) as value
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.name = 'James'
```